# Upstart session job not being run

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I created an upstart [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) which should take care of stopping my unprivileged LXC containers when shutting down or restarting the system. I placed the configuration in `~/.config/upstart/lxc-stop.conf` as described on the linked page. The content looks as follows:

```
description  "Stop running LCX containers on shutdown"

start on runlevel [06]

env LOG="/home/username/lxc-stop.log"

script
    echo "[`date`] Stopping" >> "$LOG"
    lxc-stop -n "my-container"
    echo "[`date`] Stopped: $?" >> "$LOG"
end script

pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Stopping containers" >> "$LOG"
end script

pre-stop script
    echo "[`date`] Done stopping containers" >> "$LOG"
end script
```

When I run `init-checkconf ~/.config/upstart/lxc-stop.conf`, the check succeeds. However, obviously the script never runs, as the log file is not written.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with the config? How can I debug those issues?

[edit]

- copied script to `~/.init` -- no success.
- entering `initctl start lxc-stop` gives `initctl: Unknown job: lxc-stop`

Comment: Anything in `.cache/upstart/lxc-stop.log`?

Comment: @muru No, empty directory.

Comment: when you place a file in the /etc/init.d direcory, I believe you need to run the following command after to make it subsequently execute automatically. For example, if the file in init.d is /etc/init.d/lxc-stop, you would need to run the command : `sudo update-rc.d lxc-stop defaults`

Comment: @mchid I'm slightly confused. I did not place anything in `/etc/init.d`, I'm talking about upstart session jobs.

Answer (score 0):

[Session Jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) are managed by the users own Session Init.

[Session Init](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-init) is used to manage the default graphical user session. And using Session Init on a server [is not fully supported](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#non-graphical-sessions-ubuntu-specific).